# What method do I need to override for list child to return internal data array instead of itself?

Tags: python

I needed a dynamic size queue so I inherited `list` and `Iterable` and I tested all the stuff like appending, indexing and iterating but there is a small problem. Methods like
str(DataSet) return an empty list, and the Python debugger does show an empty list, which is expected, since I don't append to the list parent but the internal data. What do I need to override to not return `self` but return `self.data`?

```
class DataSet(collections.Iterable, list):

    data = collections.deque()
    index = 0
    max = 3

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.append(other)

    def append(self, item):


        if len(self.data) >= self.max:
            self.data.popleft()

        self.data.append(item)

    def __next__(self):

        if self.index < len(self.data):

            ret = self.data[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return ret

        raise StopIteration

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.data[i]

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def setMax(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you override `__str__` ?

Comment: Provided example for str(), other stuff (like the Python debugger) also show an empty list.

Comment: If you're not going to use ``self`` for data storage, then it was utterly pointless to subclass ``list`` - NOTHING that you actually get from that inheritance will work properly in that circumstance.

Comment: Making `self.data` a class attribute is probably not a good idea. BTW, don't use `set` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `set` type.

Comment: @jasonharper How would you tackle the problem of a variable size queue?

Comment: Well, if your desired behavior is basically that of a ``deque``, then inherit from ``deque`` - actually, you might not need to define a class at all since ``deque`` already implements a limited length!  If for some reason your object can't actually be a ``deque`` (you truly need to be able to change the max length after creation, perhaps), then inherit from nothing, and implement all the methods yourself.

Comment: @PM2Ring I always wondered if that *actually* matter?
@jasonharper I the problem was maxlen of queue is read only upon object creation, I needed runtime dynamic. Figured it out, subclassed deque and overrode `append()`.

Comment: Well, if you're only creating a single instance then I guess you can use a class attribute, but it's not going to work well if you need multiple instances. ;)

Comment: And regarding shadowing built-in names, you can often get away with it, but it is confusing to others reading your code. And if you do decide to use that built-in name later in your code for its normal purpose the error message can be a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Override

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)
```

Comment: Consider adding a description to complement your code. It will help users that visit this post in the future understand how it works.